# Python: zip() returning two lists inside a tuple inside a list instead of a list of tuples of each element

Tags: python, list

list_1 and list_2 are lists returned from calling a function outside the function:

```
list_1 = [foo(x)]
list_2 = [foo(y)]

list_1 = [1,2,3,4]
list_2 = [5,6,7,8]
zipped_list = list(zip(list_1, list_2))
zipped_list = [([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8])]
```

it should be

```
zipped_list = [(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```

Any idea?

Comment: use `list_1 = foo(x)
list_2 = foo(y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the initial square brackets, just do this:

```
list_1 = foo(x)
list_2 = foo(y)
```

Your code was creating the following:

```
list_1 = [[1,2,3,4]]
list_2 = [[5,6,7,8]]
```

which are lists with one element (which happen to be lists) so the zipped result also has just one element.